# Wordpress: Permission denied when uploading to a symbolic link

Tags: wordpress

After moving my uploads folder to another location, I made a symbolic link to uploads folder inside the wp-content,

```
$> ln -s /mnt/uploads /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
```

but now it is giving me the following error:

> PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/13964be50da3eba1fa0343091276c127) [< a href='function.file-put-contents'>function.file-put-contents< /a>]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/complains/bootstrap.php on line 555, referer: http://mysite.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the uploads folder using ssh, so the owner of the new uploads folder was root instead of apache, so I gave the ownership back to apache using:

```
$> chown apache:apache /mnt/uploads
```

but the problem here was that I didn't make it recursive, so the folder "/mnt/uploads/2013/05" was still having root as the owner, so I solved it using:

```
$> chown -R apache:apache /mnt/uploads
```